# docker-compose ps doesnt show me my containers

Tags: list, docker, docker-compose, containers

Im new to docker.

I have a docker-compose.yml file like this :

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  nginx_sarahmaso:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/nginx/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - staticfiles_sarahmaso:/app/static
      - mediafiles_sarahmaso:/app/media
    ports:
      - 4000:80
    depends_on:
      - web_sarahmaso
    networks:
      spa_network_sarahmaso:

  web_sarahmaso:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - staticfiles_sarahmaso:/app/static
      - mediafiles_sarahmaso:/app/media
      - sqlite_sarahmaso:/app/db  
    env_file:
      - ./env/prod-sample
    networks:
      spa_network_sarahmaso:



networks:
  spa_network_sarahmaso:

volumes:
  sqlite_sarahmaso:
  staticfiles_sarahmaso:
  mediafiles_sarahmaso:
```

I'm deploying this on a server with a sh script running these commands :

```
 mkdir -p /app
    rm -rf /app/* && tar -xf /tmp/project.tar -C /app
    sudo docker-compose -f /app/docker-compose.yml build
    sudo supervisorctl restart react-wagtail-project
    sudo ufw allow port
```

However the supervisorctl doesnt run correctly. But the console tells me `"Successfully built dc10bd26b175"`after the docker build.

But when i run docker-compose ps or docker ps -a i dont see any containers.
Docker-compose ps asks me for a docker-compose.yml file and if i do docker-compose ps -f path_to/docker-compose.yml the console shows me the help slug :

```
List containers.

Usage: ps [options] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    -q, --quiet          Only display IDs
    --services           Display services
    --filter KEY=VAL     Filter services by a property
    -a, --all            Show all stopped containers (including those created by the run command)
```

How come i dont see my containers?

Comment: docker-compose is project based. It needs a docker-compose.yml in current working directory. Do `cd app` first and then run `docker-compose ps`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your containers are not started.

With your line `sudo docker-compose -f /app/docker-compose.yml build` you are building your container, as the console message tells you.

I do not exactly know what this line does `sudo supervisorctl restart react-wagtail-project`, but to me, it does not look like a command to START your newly built containers.

Try to explicitely start your containers by adding
`./path_to_compose/docker-compose up` or
`./path_to_compose/docker-compose up -d` to your script.